# Nullify while typing non allowed chars

Tags: javascript

I need to add a control to a text input field in order that it will allow only hashtags  on it, one per time:

```
in the form: valid_hash = /#([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/gim;


<input type="text" id="add_by_hand">
```

so far:

```
$(function() {
  var txt = $("#add_by_hand");
  var func = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode != "37" && e.keyCode != "38" && e.keyCode != "39" && e.keyCode != "40"){
        txt.val(txt.val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
    }
  }
  txt.keyup(func).blur(func);
});
```

this is okay only to avoid spaces (thus having only one hashtag per time)
but I'd like to validate it in a way that if a character that is not allowed by the valid_hash  var it's automatically removed. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your function :

```
 if(! valid_hash.test(txt.val()+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))){     
    return false; //avoid key.
}
```

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't work, it makes the same (i think) mistake i faced before, it intercepts the shift key + it doesn't replace the text at all.